# Mysql Query formatting issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, formatting

I'm building a Private Message system, and my database has multiple lines.
In database:

```
I love that song do you?

-Joe
```

But my query ends up displaying like this

```
I love that song do you? -Joe
```

Here's my query

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
$username = $user_data['username'];
?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages Where sentto1='$username'");
echo '<h2>Messages: </h2><br>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


  echo '<b>From: ';
  echo $row['from1'];
  echo '</b><br><br>';

  echo 'Subject: ';
  echo $row['subject1'];

  echo '<br><br>';
  echo 'Message: ';
  echo $row['message1'];
  echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
  }

?>
<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to replace EndOfLine with <br> :)

Comment: You can verify that the newline characters are being include in the HTML source (e.g. Right click, View page source). I think your issue is with the rendering of the HTML. A `<br>` tag inserted before each newline character may be the ticket for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), which will replace all your newline characters with HTML `<br>` tags.

```
  echo nl2br($row['message1'], false);
```